# SQLITE and foreign key

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I am looking at some database tables which are defined like this:

This is the first table-

```
CREATE TABLE Point 
(

    Position integer unique not null,  
    Name text not null,                
);
```

And second table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE namesPerPoint 
(

    PointKey integer not null,            -- unique ROWID in points table
    name text unique not null
);
```

Now, my question is how will sqlite db know that PointKey references  rowid in Positions table. Its just mentioned here in comment, for user convenience. If I myself have to do it, I will do using FOREIGN KEY constraint.
So, is this syntax correct? But this is a part of big successfully running system and all tables are defined like this only. So, I am assuming I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you create a foreign key constraint. but first, you need to `turn on` the foreign key support

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

add a primary key to the main table

```
CREATE TABLE Point 
(

    Position integer PRIMARY KEY,  
    Name text not null,                
);
```

then to add foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE namesPerPoint 
(
    PointKey integer not null,            -- unique ROWID in points table
    name text unique not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (PointKey) REFERENCES Point(Position)
);
```

PRIMARY KEY

**[Source: SQLite Foreign Key Support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)**

Comment: That means these people are doing it wrong. Its only working on their system because they themselves are maintaining data in their tables and they know what values to put it. But, if someone else tries to modify it, they may end up with corrupted tables.

Comment: Yes, thats how I normally do it. But when I saw these tables, I thought may be there is something that I don't know, thats why I asked this question

Comment: @user333422 I guess not totally *corrupted* table but ends up low performance of queries.